# Why is a keys_only query not returning strongly consistent results?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

From what I have been reading in the Google Docs and other SO questions, keys_only queries should return strongly consistent results ([here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/articles/balancing-strong-and-eventual-consistency-with-google-cloud-datastore/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23211231/strongly-consistent-queries-for-root-entities-in-gae), for example).

My code looks something like this:

```
class ClientsPage(SomeHandler):
    def get(self):
        query = Client.query()
        clients = query.fetch(keys_only=True)
        self.write(len(clients))
```

Even though I am fetching the results with the keys_only=True parameter I am getting stale results right after the creation of a new Client object (which is a root entity). If there were 2 client objects before the insertion, it keeps showing 2 after inserting and redirecting. I have to manually refresh the page in order to see the number change to 3.

I understand I could use ancestor queries, but I am testing some things first and I was surprised to see that a keys_only query returned stale results. Can anyone please explain to me what's going on?

EDIT 1:
This happened in the development server, I have not tested it in production.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eventual consistency exists because the Datastore needs time to update all indexes. Keys-only query is the same as all the other queries, except it tells the Datastore - I don't need the entire entity, just return me the key. The query still looks at the indexes to get the list of results.

In contrast, getting an entity by key does not need to look at the indexes, so it is always strongly consistent.

Comment: Thanks, I see my confusion now. I am now passing the newly formed key as an argument to my next function so that it is added if the query does not find it.